# casting in qsort()

Tags: c++, pointers

The below program sorts all the suffices of a string using `qsort()` library function.

```
int sacomp(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
    return strcmp(*(const char**)a, *(const char**)b); <------------
}

void sort(string s) 
{
    int size = s.size();
    char const *data = s.c_str();
    char const **sa = new char const *[size+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sa[i] = data+i;

    qsort(sa, size, sizeof(sa[0]), sacomp); // O(n * Lon n)
}

int main() 
{
    string s("ABCCCDEFABBABBA");
    sort(s);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand the casting done in the `sacomp()` method.

```
strcmp(*(const char**)a, *(const char**)b);
```

Why a is casted to const char** and then being de-referenced?

Comment: You should use `std::sort`, not `qsort` in C++. The latter is an old C function, and it's inferior to `std::sort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element is `char *`, therefore you should change void on `char *` and get pointer to `char *`, which is `char **`. Meanwhile strcmp needs `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

qsort passes pointer of elements. You passed sa as `char**`, so every element is `char*`, and qsort passes `char**`, finally you got `char**` in the sort function.